# How do I show a link once a file is uploaded

Tags: php, html

I had trouble finding an answer for this problem.  I would like to display a link to a page that has a video file on it but I don't want the link to appear until after the video file is uploaded.

It's a site where users upload videos so I don't want to have to manually put the links there for them after they upload their videos, nor do I want to make the links ahead of time since users will click them and there will be no video available.

So, is there a way to keep a link hidden until a file is uploaded.  Once the file is uploaded the php page where the link will be on checks to see if it exists and then if it does the link is shown, otherwise the link stays hidden.

Comment: It's only possible with ajax?

Comment: did you use insertion of data in uploading to your database?? which filename and filepath would be the most important data to be use to dislay the link for your file

Comment: yes because php itself doesn't show the link it will require javascript.

Comment: There was no insertion of data used to upload.  The uploading takes place on a form where users upload to a directory on my site.  Maybe I should ask this question in the ajax section.

Answer (score 0):

1. Each time the form that the client uses to upload a file is sent store the information of the file in a database.
2. Each time the client request the list of videos, query the database and build the web page based on the results.

Make sure to associate the uploaded files to the users, so you don't mix the up. Are you managing authentication already?

If you want to have the links appear as soon as the upload is finished without reloading the page, then you need ajax.